# Mount the Vplex Virtual Volume ( LUN ) Xen Server

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, xenserver, fiber, fibre-channel

Hello ServerFault members,

Please help me with this issue.

I am in very strange situation with my Xenserver environment. I am trying to mount the Dell EmC ( Vplex LUN ) to the Xen server HA and when I use the HBA connection I don't see the Lun.

here is the details about the environment.

XENSERVER POOL.

XENS001 & XENS002

VERSION:  XenServer release 7.5.0 (xenenterprise)

Multipath ; Enable

when I choose the HBA and probing for the LUN I don't see the Drive and it works perfectly works if I choose FCoE.

[image]
[image]

thank you so much in advance for all the help and time.

Answer (score 0):

EMC Vplex must place the exported virtual volume into a correct Storage View that includes your XenServer's initiator and a group of VPLEXs frontend director ports. I would suppose that your Storage View does not include FC ports, FCoE only.